# XAML: How set properties of an user control directly

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I created a new class library in MAUI in which a user control is defined. It is a simple user control composed by a checkbox and a label. It should be noted that in MAUI checkbox have only the box and not the associated label. The following is the XAML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiLib_CustomControls.CheckBoxExt">
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox"/>
        <Label 
            x:Name="myLabel"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

and this is the related c# code:

```
namespace MauiLib_CustomControls;

public partial class CheckBoxExt : ContentView
{
    public CheckBoxExt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CheckBox CheckBox => myCheckBox;
    public Label Label => myLabel;

}
```

I compiled this project and generated the dll which I imported in my main project. Once added in the references, I add the namespace in the xaml file

```
xmlns:MauiLib_CustomControls = "clr-namespace:MauiLib_CustomControls;assembly=MauiLib_CustomControls"
```

and use the user control in a grid

```
<MauiLib_CustomControls:CheckBoxExt x:Name="myCheckBoxExt"/>
```

Currently, if I want to set some properties or events I have to write them in the C# file because they are not available in the xaml. For example

```
this.myCheckBoxExt.Label.Text = "FROM";
this.myCheckBoxExt.CheckBox.CheckedChanged += myCheckBoxExt_CheckedChanged;
```

So, how can I set the properties of this user control directly from the xaml code as for the native controls? Consider that I would like to have available all properties and events associated to the two children controls (the checkbox and the label).

Comment: You need to use *BindableProperties* for this and expose them to XAML. Currently, your properties are not settable in XAML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties

Comment: Check this project out it does exactly what you need https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be as follows using `BindableProperty`. You can modify your custom control like this:

**Code behind**

```cs
public partial class CheckBoxExt : ContentView
{
    public bool Checked
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty);
        set => SetValue(CheckedProperty, value);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public event EventHandler<CheckedChangedEventArgs> CheckedChanged;

    public static readonly BindableProperty CheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Checked), typeof(bool), typeof(CheckBoxExt), propertyChanged: OnCheckedPropertyChanged);

    private static void OnCheckedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((CheckBoxExt)bindable).CheckedChanged?.Invoke((CheckBoxExt)bindable, new CheckedChangedEventArgs((bool)newValue));
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(CheckBoxExt));

    public CustomCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:MauiLib_CustomControls"
             x:Class="MauiLib_CustomControls.CheckBoxExt">
  <HorizontalStackLayout>

    <CheckBox
      IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type customControls:CustomCheckBox}}}"/>

    <Label 
      Text="{Binding Text, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type customControls:CustomCheckBox}}}"
      VerticalOptions="Center" 
      HorizontalOptions="Center" />

  </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**Usage**

In the using XAML code you would simply add your control:

```xml
<MauiLib_CustomControls:CheckBoxExt 
  Text="My Text"
  CheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged"/>
```

and then just add the event handler:

```cs
private async void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Checkbox changed", $"new value: {e.Value}", "OK");
}
```

**Note:** Depending on the type of control you are developing, it may be necessary to register a MAUI handler for your control. If you need assistance with that, let me know.